# How do I show a Win32 MessageBox?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a pop up message box with "Hello World" written on it. 
I started off with File>New Project>Visual C++>CLR>Windows Form Application
Then I dragged a button from the toolbox onto the form, double clicked it
entered

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
MessageBox("Hello World");
}
```

then I compiled...
but I got an error message saying

error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'const char [12]' to 'System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need:

```
MessageBox::Show("Hello World");
```

(Tested according to your instructions in Visual Studio 2005.)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what your ultimate goals are, but the subject line mentioned a "Windows Application in C" -- you've created a C++/CLI application, which isn't really the same thing.

C++/CLI is Microsoft's attempt to create a C++ dialect closer to the .NET runtime.

If you want to build a C program, start with a Visual C++ -> Win 32 Project.

In the generated code, in the _tWinMain function, add a call to the native MessageBox function:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Hello world!"), _T("My program"), MB_OK);

// ...
}
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Im trying to learn theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial
but I don't even know how to get started... I've been having trouble completing their first assignemnt =(

Comment: OK, then you shouldn't be using the CLR project types, but rather the native Win32 projects.

Try starting here: http://winprog.org/tutorial/start.html and start from a Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Project. It's probably best for you to begin with an Empty project (checkbox on page 2 of the project wizard.)